# How to prevent default tooltip showup in cross-browser manner?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I heard its hard but - possible. I simply want to do it cauz I use following jquery code to avoid slow and really small default tip showups (for title and alt attributes in a & img tags).

```
$(function() {
$('a').hover(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
     if(this.title > '')
       {
    this.t = this.title;
   // this.title = '';
    $(this).append("<span id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</span>");
    $("#tooltip")
      .css("top",(e.pageY - 20) + "px")
      .css("left",(e.pageX + 3) + "px")
      .fadeIn("fast");

       }
   },
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
   }
 );
});
```

Now, if I release //this.title = ''; in the code - it works, but tooltip runs just once and on the next hover there is no replay.

Any ideas how to override that? Thx.

Comment: can't you just set title to empty after you read its value? e.g. (untested) this might work? `this.t = this.data('title') = this.attr("title") || this.attr("title"); this.attr("title","");` .. hmm, you'd need to fix that or a bit but copy the title attribute to something else then delete it.

Comment: yeah but on a second thought.. I think this just might work (with this.title = '';)! If you show tooltip just once, users my finally ask themselves what that tip actually says lol :D ps: if its not removed - as I tested it - tooltip keeps showing as a copy (here and there, not always but sometimes). But Ill check it out!

Comment: @Joseph I re-factored my answer... much better IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: [example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFjT3/3/)

I like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) but if you want to roll your own code, I'd do this...

```
$(function(){
  // remove all titles and create tooltip span
  $('a[title]').each(function(){
    var s = $("<span class='tooltip'>"+ this.title +"</span>").hide();
    $(this).append(s).removeAttr("title");
  });

  // setup hover functions
  // tooltip spans are already present
  // we just need to position and show them or hide them
  $('a').hover(function(e){
    $(this).find("span.tooltip").css({
      top: (e.pageY - 20) + "px",
      left: (e.pageX + 3) + "px"
    }).fadeIn("fast");
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find("span.tooltip").fadeOut("fast");
  });
});
```

Comment: Triggered this troughout few browsers just now and code works like a charm! THAAAAAAANX :D PS: just wondered if you care to add some div id (with "a" tag also) so I can use this feature onto some divs also?

Comment: Just modify the selectors to use it on other elements. I.E. `$('a, div#your_id').hover(func...` and `$('a[title], div[title]').each...`

Answer (score 0):

Ignore my last answer, I just finished a Moosehead.

```
$('a').hover(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var title = $(this).attr('title');

      // assign the original title to the "tt" attribute
      $(this).attr('tt', title);  

      $(this).removeAttr('title');
      $(this).append("<span id='tooltip'>" + title + "</span>");

      $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - 20) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + 3) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
    }, function() {    

      // assign it back to what it was
      $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('tt'));

      $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    }
};
```